# Control.Databindings unexpected behaviour with Poco-Viewmodel

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I was implementing/experimenting with Databindings and INotifyPropertyChanged in Winforms when i discovered the following behaviour.

The binding-magic works from Textbox1.Text <-> Vm.Foo <-> Textbox2.Text (also the other way). But when i change Vm.Foo directly via the button.Click-Event it's not working.

What's happening here? It seems the Control.Databindings also raises a ChangedEvent on my Poco.Foo. But how? Can i do that manually too without implementing INotifyPropertyChangedim my VM?

For the sake of this example it's intentional that my Viewmodel is a Poco and not implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
class Form2 : Form
{
    private TextBox textBox1;
    private TextBox textBox2;

    public Poco Vm = new Poco();
    private Button btn;

    public class Poco
    {
        public string Foo { get; set; }
    }

    public Form2()
    {
        textBox1 = new TextBox();
        textBox2 = new TextBox();
        btn = new Button();

        textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 10);
        textBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 40);
        btn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 70);
        btn.Text = "btn";

        this.Controls.Add(textBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(textBox2);
        this.Controls.Add(btn);

        btn.Click += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Vm.Foo += "#";
        };

        this.textBox1.DataBindings.Add(nameof(Control.Text), Vm, nameof(Vm.Foo), false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        this.textBox2.DataBindings.Add(nameof(Control.Text), Vm, nameof(Vm.Foo), false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [added data bindings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158436%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) raise a *PropertyChanged* event on your textboxes and update your *Vm.Foo* because *Control.Text* is the property which has been changed and raised the event. Not VM.Foo. To raise a *PropertyChanged* Event on your *VM.Foo* without implementing *INotifyPropertyChanged* try  [Update Controls for Winforms](http://updatecontrols.net/cs/winforms.shtml)

Comment: You are having a wrong perspective.

if textBox1.Text is modified PropertyChanged is raised for this Property which is then propagated to Vm.Foo which is NOT raising an PropertyChanged. But still textBox2.Text changes.